# group by date containing certain date only

Tags: mysql, date

I have tried looking at some similar examples like group by date range and weekdays etc but I couldnt fix it on my query.

as per my sample data screenshot, I need to only return

```
sum(salesamount)/sum(salescount) for week 1
```

and

```
sum(salesamount)/sum(salescount) for week 2.
```

Each of the week contain 5 days (in this example is `wednesday - sunday`).

**My Attempt:**

```
select salesstartdate, date_add(salesstartdate, interval 5 day) as gdate,
    salesamount, salescount, sum(salesamount)/sum(salescount) as ATV
from testing
group by gdate;
```

**My desired output is:**

```
Week 1  15.34173913
Week 2  15.80365088
```

Calculation to get `week 1` is `(3507.1+3639.97+5258.77+8417.04+5994.48)/(285+273+344+478+368)`

Calculation to get `week 2` is the same as above except the date would now be from 8 to 12 of June.

[image: sample data]

Comment: can you share your table data ?

Comment: yup it is as per the screenshot above. Those are the data in my table. is that what you are referring to?

Comment: oh..it went missing:( sorry, i have re-attached. thank you wajeeh and shah

Comment: How do you define which 5 days to be taken?

Comment: Assumed it is always "Wednesday" to "Sunday" for this instance. So if next time I wanted a different 5 days I guess i can just update the query and put "Thursday" to "Monday" for instance.

Comment: What are you doing with this one `date_add(salesstartdate, interval 5 day)`?

Comment: I try to get just 5 days (example 15 June to 19 June) consist of 5 days. And when that is done the next group is the next 5 days (example 8 June - 12 June). Hm...seems that I did not specify it is from Wednesday to Sunday so how would the system knows it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a subquery. In order to first group your result set properly and then execute aggregation on it:

```
SELECT 
    concat('WEEK', ' ', weekno) as `Week #`,
    MIN(salesstartdate) as startDate,
    MAX(salesstartdate) as endDate,
    sum(salesamount)/sum(salescount) as ATV
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            salesstartdate,         
            salesamount, 
            salescount,
            WEEKOFYEAR(salesstartdate) as weekno    -- get the week number of the current year
        FROM
            weekno
        WHERE
            WEEKDAY(salesstartdate) BETWEEN 2 AND 6 -- get index of week day
    ) as weeks
GROUP BY
    weekno
```

I have used 2 MySQL functions here:

- [`WEEKOFYEAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear)
- [`WEEKDAY()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-weekday-function.php)

Output:

```
WEEK 23 | 2016-06-08 | 2016-06-12 | 15.8040
WEEK 24 | 2016-06-16 | 2016-06-19 | 15.9323
```

and without subquery as well:

```
SELECT 
    concat('WEEK', ' ', WEEKOFYEAR(salesstartdate)) as `Week #`,
    MIN(salesstartdate) as startDate,
    MAX(salesstartdate) as endDate,
    sum(salesamount)/sum(salescount) as ATV
FROM
    weekno
WHERE
    WEEKDAY(salesstartdate) BETWEEN 2 AND 6 -- get index of week day
GROUP BY
    WEEKOFYEAR(salesstartdate)
```

Comment: OMG!! that was excellent! thank you, it even give me start and end date. I have learnt new things today:) thank you so much Shah!! Perfect! thank you very much!

Comment: I was wondering in the mean time, I tried again after you prompt me the question how to define which 5 days with the following query but doesn't work. is it because my logic was wrong for the query below? SELECT 
    salesstartdate AS 'date_range 1', sum(salesamount)/sum(salescount)
FROM testing
WHERE salesstartdate >= '2016-06-08' AND salesstartdate <= '2016-06-12'
UNION
SELECT 
    salesstartdate AS 'date_range 2', sum(salesamount)/sum(salescount)
FROM testing
WHERE salesstartdate >= '2016-06-15' AND salesstartdate <= '2016-06-19' 
GROUP BY 1,2;

Comment: Your logic is hardcoded actually, though it could work but you wrote the `GROUP` condition wrong.

Comment: Oh that make sense..I did not think of that..true it wont be feasible if I have 10 weeks to union them. thank you

Comment: @Strawberry Agree, added that version too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way

```
select SUBDATE(salesstartdate, WEEKDAY(salesstartdate)) as week_range
    , sum(salesamount)/sum(salescount)
from testing
where salesstartdate between SUBDATE(salesstartdate, WEEKDAY(salesstartdate)) 
    and  date_add(SUBDATE(salesstartdate, WEEKDAY(salesstartdate)), interval 5 day))
Group by week_range
```

Comment: Are you sure its working? Because you will not have the column `week_range` at the time of grouping.